# How do I loop through a hash?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Given the following variable:

```
$test = {
  '1' => 'A',
  '2' => 'B',
  '3' => 'C',
  '4' => 'G',
  '5' => 'K',
}
```

How can loop through all assignments without knowing which keys I have?

I would like to fill a select box with the results as label and the keys as hidden values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a foreach loop on the keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = {
  '1' => 'A',
  '2' => 'B',
  '3' => 'C',
  '4' => 'G',
  '5' => 'K',
};

foreach my $key(keys %$test) {
    print "key=$key : value=$test->{$key}\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
key=4 : value=G
key=1 : value=A
key=3 : value=C
key=2 : value=B
key=5 : value=K
```

Comment: N.B. you might also want to use a `sort` preceding the `keys` function to get your data in some kind of useful/predictable order

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in function `each`:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %$test) {
  print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: This is my favorite way to iterate on a hash.  The `foreach my...` construct seems more widely used but I like how `each` deals implicitly with key/value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out what keys you have with `keys`

```
my @keys = keys %$test; # Note that you need to dereference the hash here
```

Or you could just do the whole thing in one pass:

```
print map { "<option value='$_'>$test->{$_}</option>"  } keys %$test;
```

But you'd probably want some kind of order:

```
print map { "<option value='$_'>$test->{$_}</option>"  } sort keys %$test;
```

… and you'd almost certainly be better off moving the HTML generation out to a separate [template system](http://template-toolkit.org).